# Подходящий обработчик формы

Tags: delphi

Такое задание:
Есть программа в несколько форм.

И есть у меня проблема.
Если писать всё в `OnCreate`, то все действия на форме будут происходить при самом включении программы.

А мне нужно, чтобы действия происходили только тогда, когда форма открыта `form2.Show`.
А обработчик `OnShow` не работает вообще. Просто действия не происходят...

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: А какие действия должны происходить (как-нибудь поподробнее)? По идее, на Form2.Show должно работать, но, смотря что именно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `OnCreate` - срабатывает сразу после того как приложение создает форму
- `OnShow` - когда приложение показывает форму `Visible = True` или `Show()` (если до этого было `Visible = False`)
- `OnActivate` - когда форма получает фокус ввода

Попробуй `OnActivate`.

Comment: Попробую!!